# Specify date format in WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I created a simple web service and a WSDL for it. In my WSDL I have five parameters for my SOAP response.

```
<message name="EmailStatusResponse">
    <part name='id' type='xsd:integer'/>
    <part name='name' type='xsd:string'/>
    <part name='message' type='xsd:string'/>
    <part name='createdDate' type='xsd:date'/>
    <part name='approver' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
```

I want to create a client using my WSDL with **eclipse** and **Axis2**. The format of the `createdDate` which I receive through SOAP response is DD/MM/YYYY. When I run the client it throws an `AxisFault` saying that date format of `createdDate` is incorrect.
I know this would work if I change the date format sent in SOAP response to DD/MM/YYYY or change the type of the `createdDate` parameter in WSDL to `xsd:string`.
My question is, is there a way to specify the date pattern in WSDL?

For an example something like this:
`<part name='createdDate' type='xsd:date' pattern="DD/MM/YYYY"/>` 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious if my answer below solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it a string and then restrict the pattern of the string like so:

```
<xs:simpleType name="createdDate">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This will get you the right format but you could have problems with the SOAP type being a string.

Answer (score -2):

You can use schema to have your preferred pattern?

Comment: Can you explain it little bit further? What do you mean by 'schema'?